# unable to preview js embed code on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed

I am asking user to put js (well any) embed code into a textarea e.g. the following js embed code is submitted into textarea

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://video.boston.cbslocal.com/global/video/videoplayer.js?rnd=275172;hostDomain=video.boston.cbslocal.com;playerWidth=320;playerHeight=240;isShowIcon=true;clipId=6326565;flvUri=;partnerclipid=;adTag=News;advertisingZone=CBS.BOSTON%252Fworldnowplayer;enableAds=true;landingPage=;islandingPageoverride=false;playerType=STANDARD_EMBEDDEDscript;controlsType=fixed'></script>
```

there is preview button next to textarea on click of which I get the contents of the text area and assign it to hidden div 'id_bm_embed_view_div' and later showing this div like:

```
$('#id_bm_embed_view_div').html(textarea contet);
$('#id_bm_embed_view_div').show();
```

twitter and youtube embed code seems works fine, shows proper preview, but I don't get it right for js embed code, what I am missing here?

e.g. if I put following embed code I get the proper preview of the embed code

```
<!-- Generated by EmbeVi (http://www.embevi.com) -->  <object  classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344">  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/R4j8p6zlFHs&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="pluginspage" value="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" />  <embed  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/R4j8p6zlFHs&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata" width="425" height="344" wmode="transparent" allowScriptAccess="always" pluginspage="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" flashvars="" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" loop="false" autoplay="false" autostart="false" scale="exactfit" align="middle" /> </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should scape any `/` in your submitted data.
I tried these examples:

```
$("div").html("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('hi');</script>");
// Simply put raw data in div
```

This doesn't work. It prints `");` in div.
But this works:

```
$("div").html("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('hi');<\/script>");
// Note: <\/script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I get the alert even if I don't scape the / (forward slash), where as escaping forward slash gives me js error invalid xml char